# Date Time Format AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime-format

I have a string output as "30/12/2019 12:00:00 AM" i.e "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM". I need a formatter to display date "30/12/2019 12:00:00 AM" as Dec 30 2019. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Follow [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Comment: We can help find the problem in your code, if you have any to show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date string you want to format should be either a Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats.

You cannot create a date in `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM` format using [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object in JavaScript.

Here is a simple workaround that converts the date string into a valid date object and then formats date in specified format using [AngularJS date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

```js
const app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){         
    const convertDate = date => {
        const parts = date.split('/'),
              day = parts[0],
              month = parts[1],
              year = parts[2].split(' ')[0];
              
        return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);
    };
    
    $scope.dt = convertDate('30/12/2019 12:00:00 AM');
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    {{ dt | date: 'mediumDate' }}
</div>
```